# Would derandomizing the reduction from SAT to Unique SAT imply $NP$ and $coNP$ are in $\oplus P$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat

The Unambiguous SAT problem (USAT) is to determine whether a 
given formula has a satisfying assignment, when we are 
guaranteed that it has at most one satisfying assignment.

By a theorem Valiant-Vazirani there is probabilistic
reduction from 3SAT to USAT. Given 3SAT formula $\phi$,
over $n$ variables, the algorithm produces $n+2$ formulas
$\phi_i$ with the properties:  if $\phi$ is UNSAT, all $\phi_i$
are UNSAT. Otherwise the probability that $\phi_i$ has exactly
one solution is $\ge \frac18$.

$\oplus P$ is the class of decision problems solvable by a nondeterministic Turing machine in polynomial time, where the acceptance condition is that the number of accepting computation paths is odd.

Since USAT has zero or one solution, $\oplus P$ solves USAT.

> Would derandomizing the reduction SAT to USAT imply $NP$ and $coNP$ are in  $\oplus P$?

This looks plausible to me, though [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_P) claims 
"there is a relativized universe (see oracle machine) where P = ⊕P ≠ NP = PP = EXPTIME" and $P^{\oplus P}$ is not known to even contain $NP$.

Even it can't be derandomized the reduction to USAT appears
very good in practice given $\oplus P$ oracle.

Comment: Unique-SAT is US-Complete. The problem in question is Unambiguous-SAT, which is a promise problem for complexity class UP.

Comment: If by a derandomization you mean a deterministic polytime algorithm that maps a 3CNF $\phi$ to a list of 3CNFS $\psi_1, \ldots, \psi_k$, such that if $\phi$ is unsatisfiable, than all $\psi_i$ are unsatisfiable, and if $\phi$ is satisfiable, at least one of the $\psi_i$ has a unique satisfying solution, then I see how this would imply that $\mathsf{NP}$ and $\mathsf{coNP}$ are in $\mathsf{P}^{\oplus \mathsf{P}}$. However, to show containment in $\oplus\mathsf{P}$, you need this class to be closed under unions, and I don't think that's known.

Comment: @SashoNikolov Basically I meant if I had parity P oracle in practice I will solve SAT with high probability (this is not deterministic). Your proposed reduction is very close to [this paper p. 15 Thm 5.2](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~klivans/amjourn.ps)

Answer (score 6):

The standard meaning of "derandomized Valiant-Vazirani theorem" is the following.

> There exists a deterministic polynomial time algorithm that, given a 3CNF formula $\phi$, outputs formulas $\psi_1, \ldots, \psi_k$ such that
>
> 1. If $\phi$ is not satisfiable, then none of the $\psi_i$ are.
> 2. If $\phi$ is satisfiable, at least one of the $\psi_i$ has a unique satisfying assignment.

Indeed, if the above is true, $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{P}^{\oplus \mathsf{P}}$ (a  comment by Joro suggests that this is what he actually meant). Since $\mathsf{P}^{\oplus \mathsf{P}}$ is closed under complement, it follows that $\mathsf{coNP} \subseteq \mathsf{P}^{\oplus \mathsf{P}}$ holds as well.

If a derandomized Valiant-Vazirani theorem holds relative to $\oplus P$, i.e. with the 3CNF formulas augmented by $\oplus P$ predicates, then, using Fortnow's argument in his [simplified proof](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~fortnow/papers/toda.pdf) of Toda's theorem, we would get $\mathsf{PH} \subseteq \mathsf{P}^{\oplus \mathsf{P}}$. The usual randomized Valiant-Vazirani theorem implies a randomized version of this: $\mathsf{PH} \subseteq \mathsf{BPP}^{\oplus \mathsf{P}}$. This is one of the lemmas used by Toda.

**Note**: My original answer had a bug, thanks to Emil Jeřábek for pointing it out.

Comment: Does it also imply ${\bf NP} \subseteq {\bf P ^{\bf UP}}$? ... Furthermore, as far as I know, ${\bf \oplus P}$ is closed under Turing reductions so it should be ${\bf NP} \subseteq {\bf \oplus P}$? No? Please let me know if I missed something.

Comment: @TayfunPay could you provide a reference for the closure of $\oplus \mathsf{P}$ that you are claiming?

Comment: The original Paper by Papadimitriou and Zachos where they show that ${\bf \oplus P}= {\bf \oplus P}^{\bf \oplus P}$.. And since when a given class is low for itself, then it is closed under Turing reductions... ${\bf \oplus P}= {\bf  P}^{\bf \oplus P}$. Am I missing something? Ok

Comment: I guess it is very simple actually, $\mathsf{P}^{\oplus \mathsf{P}} \subseteq \oplus \mathsf{P}^{\oplus \mathsf{P}} = \oplus \mathsf{P}$. Thanks!

Comment: @SashoNikolov One of my profs said we cannot derandomize VV theorem. In what sense is this statement true? If $P=BPP$ can we derandomize VV and hence $PH$ is in $P^{\oplus P}$ is a conjecture or am I missing something?

Comment: @Turbo I do not know what your professor meant. I do not think P=BPP itself implies a derandomization of VV. But there are plausible sounding assumptions under which VV can be derandomized, see http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539700389652

Comment: @SashoNikolov Strange is there a reason why VV derandomization would be eluded by P=BPP?

Comment: @SashoNikolov $\oplus P$ sounds like can be solved by Permanent mod 2 which is det over F_2. Then why is \oplus P not in P?

Comment: @Turbo "sounds like" is not a proof. The reduction from a #P-complete problem to the permanent does not have to preserve parities. For example, the reduction from #3SAT here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-completeness_of_01-permanent multiplies the number of satisfying assignments by an even number.

Comment: The "easy exercise" does not appear correct. You would need a stronger assumption  $\mathrm{NP^{\oplus P}\subseteq\oplus P}$ for the inductive argument to go through.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek It avoids that induction. It replaces randomized Valiant-Vazirani with derandomized version in Toda's approach.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks, I think I have made a mistake there. It *would* work (in the same way as in Fortnow's paper) if a "derandomized Valiant-Vazirani" theorem were true with an oracle for $\oplus P$.